# Display blank space if data is not present for a particular date

Tags: highcharts

I want to display blank space if data is not present for those dates in Highstock. If data is not present for the month of November, then blank space should be displayed on Highstock for that month. For October and December, data should be displayed.

```js
$(function() {

  var data = [
    /* Sep 2009 */
    [1253836800000, 26.05],
    [1254096000000, 26.59],
    [1254182400000, 26.48],
    [1254268800000, 26.48],
    /* Oct 2009 */
    [1254355200000, 25.84],
    [1254441600000, 26.41],
    [1254700800000, 26.57],
    [1254787200000, 27.14],
    [1254873600000, 27.18],
    [1254960000000, 27.04],
    [1255046400000, 27.21],
    [1255305600000, 27.26],
    [1255392000000, 27.15],
    [1255478400000, 27.33],
    [1255564800000, 27.22],
    [1255651200000, 26.86],
    [1255910400000, 27.12],
    [1255996800000, 28.39],
    [1256083200000, 29.27],
    [1256169600000, 29.31],
    [1256256000000, 29.13],
    [1256515200000, 28.93],
    [1256601600000, 28.20],
    [1256688000000, 27.49],
    [1256774400000, 28.05],
    [1256860800000, 26.93],
    /* Dec 2009 */
    [1259625600000, 28.14],
    [1259712000000, 28.03],
    [1259798400000, 28.07],
    [1259884800000, 27.62],
    [1260144000000, 26.99],
    [1260230400000, 27.12],
    [1260316800000, 28.26],
    [1260403200000, 28.06],
    [1260489600000, 27.81],
    [1260748800000, 28.14],
    [1260835200000, 27.74],
    [1260921600000, 27.86],
    [1261008000000, 27.41],
    [1261094400000, 27.92],
    [1261353600000, 28.32],
    [1261440000000, 28.62],
    [1261526400000, 28.87],
    [1261612800000, 29.86],
    [1261958400000, 30.23],
    [1262044800000, 29.87],
    [1262131200000, 30.23],
    [1262217600000, 30.10]
  ];
  /*$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
   */ // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
      ordinal: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
});
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AsmitaJ/eLm7ajhn/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to play around with [`gapSize`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cspline%3E.gapSize):

> Defines when to display a gap in the graph. A gap size of 5 means that if the distance between two points is greater than five times that of the two closest points, the graph will be broken.

```
series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    gapSize: 5,
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    }
}]
```

Working example below:

```js
$(function() {

  var data = [
    /* Sep 2009 */
    [1253836800000, 26.05],
    [1254096000000, 26.59],
    [1254182400000, 26.48],
    [1254268800000, 26.48],
    /* Oct 2009 */
    [1254355200000, 25.84],
    [1254441600000, 26.41],
    [1254700800000, 26.57],
    [1254787200000, 27.14],
    [1254873600000, 27.18],
    [1254960000000, 27.04],
    [1255046400000, 27.21],
    [1255305600000, 27.26],
    [1255392000000, 27.15],
    [1255478400000, 27.33],
    [1255564800000, 27.22],
    [1255651200000, 26.86],
    [1255910400000, 27.12],
    [1255996800000, 28.39],
    [1256083200000, 29.27],
    [1256169600000, 29.31],
    [1256256000000, 29.13],
    [1256515200000, 28.93],
    [1256601600000, 28.20],
    [1256688000000, 27.49],
    [1256774400000, 28.05],
    [1256860800000, 26.93],
    /* Dec 2009 */
    [1259625600000, 28.14],
    [1259712000000, 28.03],
    [1259798400000, 28.07],
    [1259884800000, 27.62],
    [1260144000000, 26.99],
    [1260230400000, 27.12],
    [1260316800000, 28.26],
    [1260403200000, 28.06],
    [1260489600000, 27.81],
    [1260748800000, 28.14],
    [1260835200000, 27.74],
    [1260921600000, 27.86],
    [1261008000000, 27.41],
    [1261094400000, 27.92],
    [1261353600000, 28.32],
    [1261440000000, 28.62],
    [1261526400000, 28.87],
    [1261612800000, 29.86],
    [1261958400000, 30.23],
    [1262044800000, 29.87],
    [1262131200000, 30.23],
    [1262217600000, 30.10]
  ];
  /*$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
   */ // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
      ordinal: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      gapSize: 5,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
});
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLm7ajhn/10/)

Comment: Thank you for your response.This worked my solution.